# JS - Pause custom alert()

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've edited the default `alert()` function like this:

```
window.alert = function(str){
    //custom alert
}
```

Essentially, the new function will show an HTML `<div>` modal.

Backstory:

I want to answer to this question because I am having a problem. The alert is hidden and will show when the custom alert function is called. So the custom alert is basically showing the element and changing it's text. **Therefore, when I have multiple `alert()` calls, only the last message is displayed! :(**

But, unlike the default alert box. It of course won't pause the webpage until the alert goes away like the default `alert()` function.

**Is it possible to imitate this "pause the webpage" behavior?**

**Also, is there another way other then using `setTimeout()` to check if `isCustomAlertOpen == true` to delay another custom alert from triggering until the current one is dismissed?**

---

### Edit:

**Is there a way to queue up the custom alerts?**

I don't mind jQuery, but I thought it might be overpowered here.

My question title is bad. Can someone think of a better title for me please?

Comment: The 'pause' behaviour of `alert()` is generally considered to be a bad thing. It can lead to erratic behaviour, because events can still be triggered while the alert is on screen, but instead of happening when they are triggered, they queue up and wait for the alert to be cleared. When the alert is cleared, they will then be run, but may not be run in the order you expect them to be. It's even worse if you have an alert inside a timed event method - the events will still be getting triggered while the original alert is displayed, so you may end up with an unstoppable flood of alert boxes.

Comment: Also, if you were able to pause the website, how were you (technically) planning on resuming it again?

Comment: @Siguza Until the alert dialog is dismissed. Then presumably, the events will continue

Comment: @Simba Oh~ I understand now. But now I would like the alert boxes to queue up. Is there is way?

Comment: Yes there is. But don't do it. `setInterval(function() {alert("Oh help, I'm stuck in a sea of alert boxes");}, 100);`  (hint: *really*; you don't want run this code)

Comment: @Simba I don't think that is what I meant... I mean "queue up" as in after user clicked "OK", it then display the next message if there is one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to block the execution because JavaScript is asynchronous (except obviously 3 modal functions and XmlHttpRequest).

For the same reason, you can't wait for a previous alert to be closed, but you can use events to create a stack of alerts using this pattern:

```
window.alert = (function() {
    var stack = [];

    var showNextAlert = function() {
        var div = document.createElement("div");
        /* Here, configure the div, show the string from stack[0] and add it to the document ... */
        var okButton = /* ... */;

        okButton.addEventListener("click", function() {
            div.parentNode.removeChild(div);

            stack = stack.slice(1);

            if(stack.length > 0) {
                showNextAlert();
            }
        });
    }

    return function(msg) {
        stack.push(msg);

        if(stack.length == 1) {
            // Show it immediately if the stack is empty
            showNextAlert();
        }
    };
})();
```

You should also use another name for this function instead of changing native properties (here `window.alert`).

Comment: I've never thought of "queuing" in JS. Thanks. I think I will try the concept! I may accept your answer after I try it out. :)

Comment: Just a question, does `return function` just run the anonymous alert function again with `msg` as argument?

Comment: @DanielCheung No, the function which is returned is the one which will be visible in `window.alert`. This is called a module pattern.

Comment: This answer contains some things I haven't seen before. Let me research them first and I'll ask you more. :)

Comment: If alert is not finished (e.g. I called `alert()` twice and you are on the 1st dialog), does the function remains active and `stack` can still be accessible and can retain messages strings by calling new `alerts()`?

Comment: @DanielCheung `alert` will be shown in the same order that it has been called, and the next queued `alert` will only be created/shown after closing the previous one.

Comment: I got it working. Thanks! I've never use this type of code before. I've learnt something new :)

Comment: Just one thing, I had to remove the event handler each time within the "click" handler, I'm using jQuery and it duplicated the number of click handler calls every time the button is clicked because I'm not removing the dialog, just hiding it. Let's say I log to the console every time the OK button is clicked, it logs 1 time on 1st click, logs 2 times on 2nd click, logs 4 times on 3rd click, logs 8 times on 4th click, etc.

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible to imitate this "pause the webpage" behavior?

The answer to this is no. There are ways to block the ui (sync ajax call, long loop etc). But you wouldn't be able to stop these when the user has click the ok button.

A better approach would be to restructure the code so that it didn't run synchronously. Ie you wouldn't need to block the ui while waiting for the user.

> Also, is there another way other then using setTimeout() to check if isCustomAlertOpen == true to delay another custom alert from triggering until the current one is dismissed?

One way to do this is: instead of setting a flag in one place and checking it repeatedly in another. You can use the concept of events. One part of code is waiting for an event to be triggered and another part triggers it. There is a library in jQuery which can do this for you or you could read up on it and write your own.

Comment: I was refering to ```$(elem).on(...)``` and ```$(elem).trigger(...)``` for that part. But you would still need a queue like Sebastien C. shows